# @font-face isn't working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Im using the latest version of chrome and it won't show me the font, while it does in other browsers. Already tried several things before to try and fix it, but no success.

Code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'nexa_boldregular';
src: url('../fonts/nb-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/nb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/nb-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/nb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/nb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../    fonts/nb-webfont.svg#nexa_boldregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'nexa_lightregular';
src: url('nl-webfont.eot');
src: url('nl-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('nl-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('nl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('nl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('nl-webfont.svg#nexa_lightregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'the_bold_fontbold';
src: url('theboldfont-webfont.eot');
src: url('theboldfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('theboldfont-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('theboldfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('theboldfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('theboldfont-webfont.svg#the_bold_fontbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Declaration:

```
.menu {

height: 110px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "nexa_boldregular";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet in .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Try specifying font-weight and font-style for each @font-face reference

Try using "" instead of '' for the url and format

Did you correctly reference the font-family later in the CSS?

Do you have your font-face at the top of your css file ?

Disable DirectWrite: type chrome://flags/ in the address bar and find the option labeled 'Disable DirectWrite'. If this does fix the issue, you should log a bug with the examples of your text rendering so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Tried all of them, and font-face is at the top of my css, but nothing worked

Comment: Chrome had a bug which would prevent font-face from working properly once in the past but you said your chrome is up-to-date. which version do you have ? do you have svg font ? also try with new fonts

Comment: It works now, I think clearing my cache somehow did the trick